# Sliding OSX Dock type "sidebar" rather embedded QDockWidget type?

Tags: qt

I want to make a sliding "sidebar" similar to the functionality of the OSX "Dock" (e.g. mouse passes edge of screen and Dock slides out). I've been playing around with `QDockWidget` but since that is embedded in the window layout, it causes everything to shift when it becomes visible.

Can someone suggest a way to implement this?

- Doesn't need to float (as a separate window/tool bar)
- Should scale to window height (e.g. window can be fullscreen or default size)
- Doesn't need to slide (animate) if that is complicated.

I'm new to Qt and so don't want to over-think this. Is this just a matter of a custom widget or should I be looking at a borderless window? The custom widget approach seems right but I don't know how to specify that it overlay other window content and also scale if the window scales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QDockWidget` has nothing to do with what you want - behaviorally. Just because it's called a Dock widget doesn't mean it's the same "Dock" concept as in OS X. It merely means that it docks somewhere. `QDockWidget`'s documentation quite explicitly explains what is meant by the docking behavior.

The code below implements the behavior you seem to want. Whether it's good design or not is arguable. The reason the code is "convoluted" seems to hint that nobody is expected to come up with such a UI design. What's wrong with actually clicking a button somewhere to display the slider window?

The code works under both Qt 4.8 and 5.1.

Note: This begs to be implemented in Qt Quick 2. That's what it was designed for :) Of course Qt 4.6+ improved the behavior of the QWidget-moving animations, and Qt 5 does further tweaks, but really this code smells bad and there's a good reason it does: QWidget API, while powerful, ultimately encapsulates a set of APIs that date to 1984 when the original Macintosh was released. There's only so much you can do when you have to composite results from a bunch of stacked painters. In Qt Quick, the rendering is done by the GPU. The animation amounts to passing a couple of new floats to the GPU to update a single transformation matrix. That's it.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGradient>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

class Slider : public QWidget {
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        QPainter p(this);
        QLinearGradient g(QPointF(0,0), QPointF(rect().bottomRight()));
        g.setColorAt(0, Qt::blue);
        g.setColorAt(1, Qt::gray);
        p.setBackground(g);
        p.eraseRect(rect());
        p.setPen(Qt::yellow);
        p.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 48));
        p.drawText(rect(), "Click Me To Hide");
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        hide();
    }
public:
    explicit Slider(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    }
};

class Window : public QWidget {
    QGridLayout m_layout;
    Slider m_slider;
    QLabel m_label;
    QPropertyAnimation m_animation;
public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0) :
        QWidget(parent, f),
        m_layout(this),
        m_slider(this),
        m_animation(&m_slider, "pos")
   {
        setMouseTracking(true);
        m_layout.addWidget(&m_label);
        m_slider.hide();
        m_slider.setMouseTracking(false);
        m_animation.setStartValue(QPoint(-width(), 0));
        m_animation.setEndValue(QPoint(0, 0));
        m_animation.setDuration(500);
        m_animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InCubic);
    }
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *) {
        if (window() && QCursor::pos().x() <= window()->geometry().topLeft().x()) {
            showSlider();
        }
    }
    void childEvent(QChildEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->added() && ev->child()->isWidgetType()) {
            ev->child()->installEventFilter(this);
            static_cast<QWidget*>(ev->child())->setMouseTracking(true);
        }
    }
    bool event(QEvent * ev) {
        eventFilter(this, ev);
        return QWidget::event(ev);
    }
    bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) {
            auto pos = QCursor::pos();
            if (window() && window()->isFullScreen()) {
                if (pos.x() <= window()->geometry().topLeft().x()) {
                    showSlider();
                }
            }
            m_label.setText(QString("%1, %2").arg(pos.x()).arg(pos.y()));
        }
        return false;
    }
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) {
        m_slider.resize(size());
        m_animation.setStartValue(QPoint(-width(), 0));
    }
    Q_SLOT void showSlider() {
        if (m_slider.isVisible() || (window() && qApp->activeWindow() != window())) return;
        m_slider.raise();
        m_slider.show();
        m_animation.start();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It's a GUI element from a project I'm redoing in Qt and it actually works quite well. The sidebar trigger when in window mode (not full screen) is `if the mouseX <= window.left`. Still getting familiar with Qt so QDockWidget seemed like something to check out.

Comment: So you have an application that reacts whenever your mouse is to the left of its window, in a global manner? That's crazy. You don't want that. It's a terrible design.

Comment: It really does work well ;-) The sidebar functionality is disabled if the window doesn't have focus (i.e. is in the background) or if the mouse is being pressed/dragged.

Comment: Hey thanks. It works ;-) A lot of code for me to chew on there. FWIW, the set up is that the sidebar is @ 1/4 screen width. The gesture is that it slides on when with the mouse.x >= window.left trigger and then slides off if the mouse.x > sidebar.right + 50. It's fast and fluid with a trackpad for showing the sidebar and then 2-finger scrolling through a list of images.